# IdentityServer authentication for admin application in the same host

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I have an ASP.NET MVC application for hosting an IdentityServer3, but I want to host Angular + WebAPI 2 custom administration app on that same host. That admin app is using oidc-client library for authentication. Below is my Startup class for configuring IdentityServer and calling UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication method. As you can see I called that method in a async Task because that happened to soon, before IdentityServer started.

Authentication works, my Angular ajax requests are filled with valid access tokens, but I dont get any Claims on WebApi controllers. ClaimsPrincipal have empty Claims list, and IsAuthenticated is false.
Also my client configuration is properly set. Is there something wrong with this setup?

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Trace()
            .CreateLogger();


        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();

        factory.Register<IdentityDatabaseModel>(new Registration<IdentityDatabaseModel>(typeof(IdentityDatabaseModel)));
        factory.Register<UserDataService>(new Registration<UserDataService>(typeof(UserDataService)));
        factory.Register<TokenDataService>(new Registration<TokenDataService>(typeof(TokenDataService)));
        factory.Register<ClaimsDataService>(new Registration<ClaimsDataService>(typeof(ClaimsDataService)));
        factory.Register<ClientDataService>(new Registration<ClientDataService>(typeof(ClientDataService)));


        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(typeof(UserService));

        factory.RefreshTokenStore = new Registration<IRefreshTokenStore, RefreshTokenStore>();
        factory.ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore, ClientStore>();


        factory.UseInMemoryScopes(WebApplication1.Models.IS.Scopes.Get());

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(), 
            Factory = factory,
            RequireSsl = false,
            LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
            {
                //EnableHttpLogging = true,
                EnableKatanaLogging = true,
                EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
                WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true
            },
            EnableWelcomePage = false
        };
        app.UseIdentityServer(options);

        #region IdentityServer authentication
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:17343",
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "openid", "email", "roles", "profile" },
                ClientId = "lsidentity",
                ClientSecret = "secret"
            });
        });
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are using wrong scopes in your web api. Your web api should define its own scopes in which it needs to define which claims you want in the access token which will then be pushed in and be available in your web api controllers

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I needed to configure IssuerName and SigningCertificate in WebApi configuration, so it looks like this:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:17343",
            //Authority = "http://192.168.254.3:303",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "openid",
                "email", "profile" },
            IssuerName = "http://localhost:17343", //added this
            SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(), // ...and this
            // client credentials for the introspection endpoint
            ClientId = "lsidentity",
            ClientSecret = "secret".Sha256()
        });
```

There was an issue on github, but I did not find it at first.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/38

There is also no need to call this as Task, it works fine now.